# how to use membership provider in master page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, master-pages

I use membership in my ASP.NET pages without any problem but i can't use it in master page.  when i type membership in site.master.cs it can't be detected.  How i can use membership in my master page?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't master pages is not meant to be run on the browser like normal page, we use it it just to create website layout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do but this here describes how to setup your membership provider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx.

To the best of my knowledge there is no direct connection between master pages and membership.

If you are talking about the login control in asp.net here is an explanation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In general, membership provider in master page is not recommended.  Still, itz quite possible to do so.  Just verify you invoke the site in right way. Refresh the project reference of System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)